# Play framework (Websocket): get browser info from request header

Tags: playframework, http-headers, websocket

I am using code from [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/qy36tA80Ft0/AVtWl-ymZRcJ) example to get client's browser info. But the key **user-agent** is available only for Firefox for my case, there is no key available for Chrome or Safari for this key. So, I am getting *None* object for Chrome or Safari. Can anyone please provide a generic way to get information like browser name, version etc from a Play! controllers?

### Update

I am using Websocket protocol, not http (though they are similar in many ways) and I am using Play 2.1.0 (using Java 1.7.0_17 and Scala 2.10.0). My code is like `def actorWebSocket = WebSocket.async[String] { implicit request => ...` and sending request to my server from http://websocket.org/echo.html. (All the browsers I have tested with support websocket). Though simple http request DOES show User-Agent for Firefox, Safari and Chrome, it is the websocket that is failing to show User-Agent for Safari and Chrome. @nico_ekito and @le_douard suggested that it might be a browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually play framework gives us everything (even a lot of know headers name). This is the code within a controller class' static function

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static Result index() {
        String userAgent = request().headers().get(Http.HeaderNames.USER_AGENT);
        return ok(userAgent);
    }
}
```

Naturally I assume you are pointing to routes.Application.index() somewhere in your routes file.

If you are also wondering how to parse the user agent,I also advise you to check out :
https://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/

I used it in a project 6 months ago, I do not know how updated it was but it has worked great for me when I needed it for more useful and readable informations.

### Some browsers do not fully implement what WebSockets protocol should have

After all it is a protocol still under definition/development.

For chrome it is a bug with a ticket
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128170

Apparently it has been fixed recently and should be rolled out soon?
I assume it is the same with Safari.

Comment: the answer is great but you need to replace 'HeadersNames' with 'HeaderNames'

Comment: On Play 2.5 it's `Http.HeaderNames` not `Http.HeadersNames`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it works in my app with the "User-Agent" key:

```
request.headers.get("User-Agent")
```

Comment: In Firefox, I get a k=>v map like this: *User-Agent => Buffer(Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0)*
But, neither Chrome nor Safari shows any key named **User-Agent**

Comment: Are you using a front end proxy (apache, nginx...) ?

Comment: And what version of Play ? 1.x, 2.x ?

Comment: I am using Play 2.1.0 (using Java 1.7.0_17 and Scala 2.10.0). FYI, I am using a web socket like : `def actorWebSocket = WebSocket.async[String] { implicit request => ...` and sending request to my server from http://www.websocket.org/echo.html. (All the browsers I have tested with support websocket).

Comment: Did you try without using websocket, but with a simple http request ?

Comment: Simple http request does show User-Agent for Firefox, Safari and Chrome. But it is the websocket that is failing to show User-Agent for Safari and Chrome. Do you think that it is the browser that is responsible or should I issue ticket in Play! framework issue tracker?

Comment: From the [Play doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaWebSockets), "A WebSocket has access to the request headers (from the HTTP request that initiates the WebSocket connection), allowing you to retrieve standard headers and session data. However, it doesn’t have access to a request body, nor to the HTTP response." And since it works with Firefox, it could be an issue with Chrome and Safari.

Comment: It is a bug of the browsers you have mentioned ... see my answers for links

Answer (score 0):

Having UserAgentUtils-1.6.jar in a lib directory in my play 2.0.4 project, I have been using user-agent in this way, for example to recognize an iPhone Simulator call :
at the top of my controller :

```
import nl.bitwalker.useragentutils.UserAgent;
```

and in the method :

```
    UserAgent userAgent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(Http.Context.current().request().getHeader("User-Agent"));
        Boolean iphone_l = false;
        if (userAgent.getOperatingSystem().equals("MAC_OS_X") &&
            userAgent.getOperatingSystem().getManufacturer().equals("APPLE") &&
            userAgent.getOperatingSystem().getGroup().equals("MAC_OS_X") &&
            userAgent.getOperatingSystem().getDeviceType().equals("COMPUTER") &&
            userAgent.getBrowser().equals("CFNETWORK") &&
            userAgent.getBrowser().getGroup().equals("CFNETWORK") &&
            userAgent.getBrowser().getManufacturer().equals("CFNETWORK")) {
            iphone_l = true;
        }
```

...worked fine even in Chrome (not tried IE) but crashes if the request is from Excel sheet with wininet.dll for http request.

I that helps...

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
String agent = request().getHeader(Http.HeaderNames.USER_AGENT);
```